# Is it possible to buy an UK Nintendo eShop card with a non-UK PayPal account?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I’ve tried the [PayPal Gifts page](https://www.paypal-gifts.com/uk/nintendo-eshop-cards.html) but I keep getting an error. Nintendo UK does not respond to my emails and PayPal could not fix this issue either. I’ve also tried gamepointsnow.com but they don’t sell to my country (Croatia).

Comment: I tried using my Paypal account on that website, and I got an error that it couldn't be processed. I tried it with a second (business) account of mine, and I got the same thing. Most likely there is a Paypal limitation in play here. Since Paypal owns Paypal Gifts, only Paypal could actually tell you what's going on. Alternatively, you could try to find another website to buy these from, however a recommendation would be off topic.

Comment: See my answer, you wont be able to buy that Nintendo card with your PayPal account even if you try to use vpn's or something.. your paypal account is adressed outside the uk and there is no way to change this without contancting the paypal support but anyways good question +1

Comment: You could try cardscodes.com. I've bought some PSN UK cards there in the past, because I have a similar problem as I don't live in the UK either. I don't know if they sell to Croatia though and I can't promise the site is 100% trustworthy but the codes I bought there all arrived and worked.

Comment: If you want something specific and not just wallet funds, you can try to buy e-shop stuff from game.co.uk as well with PayPal: http://www.game.co.uk/en/games/nintendo-eshop/wii-u/?attributeName1=Shop%20By&sortColumn=popular&sortTypeStr=DESC&inStockOnly=false&listerOnly=true&provenance=Download&attributeValue1=107&cm_sp=cattoys20offWBW-_-header-_-wiiueshopgames The wallet cards are only sold as actual cards and not as email though, so they can't be bought with PayPal. I've only tried these things with PSN downloads, so I don't know if it works the same way with the Nintendo e-shop.

Comment: Have you tried using [Shipito](http://www.shipito.com/)? They'll ship it to Austria and then ship it to you. It's a roundabout solution and it'll cost money to ship, but it might work.

Answer (score 2):

From the [**Terms and Conditions**](https://www.paypal-gifts.com/uk/terms-and-conditions/#purchase) on www.paypal-gifts.com

> - If you are buying an item, unless otherwise agreed with the Retailer:
>
>   - you must pay PayPal Digital Gifts for the item using a **valid PayPal account with a registered address in the UK**; and
>   - your purchase of the item will not complete until after your payment to PayPal Digital Gifts has completely cleared.

To answer your question: **No** it is not possible to buy an UK Nintendo eShop card without a valid UK Paypal Account on paypal-gifts as long as the retailer dont say so.

Here's a [**list of retailers (in europe) ordered by country**](https://cdn02.nintendo-europe.com/media/downloads/support_1/nintendo_3ds_14/Nintendo_eShop_Cards_10Nov2014.pdf) where you could buy eShop cards but i dont know if you'll find UK cards there. I'm sorry but I wont tell you were exactly you can buy what you're looking for because questions like "where can i buy XYZ" are not allowed neither recommendations are but **Yes** you can find what you're looking for if you take your time searching for it.

Comment: Just because it doesn't work on paypal-gifts.com doesn't mean there's no other retailer where it works. The question was not just about paypal-gifts.com but if there is a way in general, and there might be.

Comment: you're right, but we're not allowed to make any recommendation on resellers but what i can do is to give use this list https://cdn02.nintendo-europe.com/media/downloads/support_1/nintendo_3ds_14/Nintendo_eShop_Cards_10Nov2014.pdf which lists resellers of eshop cards

Comment: i added those information in the answer to match it up